# how to force change keyboard to english language in IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have two keyboard,1 is **Default keyboard** and 1more is **thirdparty** keyboard. i want to ask that . how to change keyboard when i click on some textview.?
Thankyou

Comment: You can't. The user has the control over the keyboard. And that's the way it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible programmatically. only user can switch between keyboard by using  *“next keyboard key"*

> When more than one keyboard is enabled, the system keyboard includes a
>   Globe key that lets the user switch keyboards. Your custom keyboard
>   may require a similar “next keyboard” key.

- [Custom keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html)
- [Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/extensions/custom-keyboards/)

[image]